# Phone call speakerphone/earpiece equalizer

Tags: calls, nexus-5, speakerphone, equalizer

Is there an application or tweak that will allow me to equalize Phone call audio coming out of the speaker/earpiece?

Similar to how AudioFX equalizes for media audio?